# Audio Processing Server Workflow with Python

Tags: python, audio, server, serverless, audio-processing

I typically reside on the front-end of the stack, but I need to do some audio processing work on a server and download the results.

I want a user to be able to upload an MP3 file to a server and have it process the file using a Python script and allow the user to download the result. The process could take anywhere from 10-20 minutes so I’ll need to notify the user once the process is finished.

I know enough about how to upload the MP3 file to the server, but then I’m at my end. I’m not sure how to kick off the Python script, store the result on a web server, and then offer it up a a temporary download.

Could someone explain to me in big strokes how I might go about doing this? I’m not expecting anyone to do the work for me, but I’m looking for advice where I can start reading about how to do some of this.

Could this a job for serverless functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example of a "background" or asynchronous task. Both from the perspective of user (person does not really want to sit around waiting for 20 minutes), and the web server (which should not be hanging on this request).

The recommended way of dealing with this is some sort of task/job queue system.

When the file is uploaded, web server creates and submits a task to the queue. It then returns "job accepted", and completes the request.
This task is then processed async, preferably by a backend worker process.
When the worker complete, the job results are stored in a database. THe worker can also construct a URL that can be used to view this result.
This URL can then be sent to the user (say via email), to access the result.
The web frontend should from this URL render a page based on the results stored in the database.

A good open-source and vendor independent task queue stack for Python is [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). For a small app you can use Redis as both message broker and result backend. For a larger app I recommend using RabbitMQ as the message backend, and Postgres/MySQL for results.

This [two-part blog series](http://blog.codepath.com/2012/11/15/asynchronous-processing-in-web-applications-part-1-a-database-is-not-a-queue/) is a good introduction to the topic.